# Airflow Relative Imports

Tags: python, python-import, airflow

I'm trying to import a module from two directories above the /dags directory. My folder structure looks like this:

```
app
 --> __init__.py
 --> my_module
    --> __init__.py
 --> airflow
    --> dags
        --> my_dag.py
        --> __init__.py
```

I've tried this, which pylint gives no errors for:

```
from app import my_module
```

However this gives the error `ImportError: No module named 'app'` when running airflow initdb. How do I import my_module in my_dag.py?

Comment: You might need to have a __init__.py under app also.

Comment: @JimTodd forgot to specify that, I have one there as well.

Comment: What is the dags folder specified in your airflow.cfg?

Comment: @nightgaunt /app/airflow/dags

Comment: Are you running airflow within docker? Are you calling the `airflow initdb` from app folder or somewhere else?

Comment: So many questions just like this one.  No satisfactory answers.  I can't believe Airflow is used for production.